# Is there a good ssh jail solution for Ubuntu 12....?

Tags: ssh, chroot

Is there a good how-to/tutorial on setting up a chrooted ssh environment on Ubuntu 12.04LTS.

I'm NOT interested in chrooted sftp which is easy to implement.

It's jailing users in their home directory when they log in via ssh that I'm interested in.

Grateful for any help,

Thank you